# Add level in axis title in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know if it is possible to group axis labels and make multiple level labels using ggplot2 in R ? I can do it with Excel, but it is very ugly ! 
Actualy, my code is the following (I'm making a stacked bar chart to show relative proportions of bacteria in my samples) :

```
DF <- read.table(text="taxon Bacteria1 Bacteria2 Bacteria3 [...]
Sample1 ...
Sample2 ...
Sample3 ...", header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)

DF1<-melt(DF, id.var="taxon")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF1, aes(x = taxon, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Here is an example of what I want to do:

[image]

Comment: You can mimic this with facets.

Comment: Have you tried Tableau instead of Excel? Maybe an alternative worth checking out, before spending hours in "hacking" grid & ggplot.

Comment: or you could just add the other levels using Adobe Illustrator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [order data to plot barplot in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837281/order-data-to-plot-barplot-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Another option: placeing a customized `tableGrob` below or even a [2nd ggplot](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/ggplot2-labelling-data-series-and-adding-a-data-table/). (You'll find plenty of examples on SO.)

Answer (score 0):

Plotting microbial proportions is a common problem, so this has already been asked (and answered very well) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20837643/3424793).

That solution is optimised for all of your values to be scaled to 1 i.e. 100% (which makes sense to me as a biologist).

You have an unlabelled sample between your control and membrane in the excel snapshot that is not scaled to 100% (which seems weird), but if you need to do that, then just add a dummy value to that particular sample, and have it filled with the same colour as your background. Finally, you can remove that particular class from the legend in Illustrator, where you will likely need to clean up the figure anyway.